# Search taxonomy terms, not posts

Tags: search

I want to generate a list of Custom Taxonomy terms, searching through the searchform. I don't need to return posts associated the the term, I want to return the terms themselves that will link to get_term_link()

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to retrieve terms that match your search query like :

```
$termsResult = get_terms( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME', 'search=SEARCH_QUERY' );
```

where,

**CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME** is your custom taxonomy and
**SEARCH_QUERY** is the string which you are using to search for terms.

Afterwards you can generate list like :

```
if ( ! empty( $termsResult ) && ! is_wp_error( $termsResult ) ){
  echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termsResult as $term ) {
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $term ).'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Gah!! I can't believe it was that easy! I couldn't find much about this anywhere out there. Thanks so much.